# can i use cluster for many cpu-bound jobs?

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing, threadpool, rmi, hazelcast

I have a java based server accepting clients requests and the client requests are cpu-bound jobs and the jobs have no dependency between them. My server is equipped with a thread pool having number of threads equal to the number of processors(or number of cores) in the system but server performance is low and client's requests wait for thread availability. Can cluster help me in this scenario? I want to use cluster and I want to distribute the jobs to nodes so that client's request wait time can be eliminated. help me in this regard. Also tell me about the framework I should use. can RMI technology help me? should I use hazelcast?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the distributed ExecutorService to distribute your operations to the different nodes and offload them to your own threadpool.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pretty good compute grid frameworks that will do the job. You can start by googling "java grid computing" or "java cluster computing". To name a few:

- [JPPF](http://www.jppf.org)
- [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.org/)
- [HTCondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/)
- [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)
- [Unicore](http://www.unicore.eu)
- etc ...